# Condition for f and g to intersect

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-equations

For $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Neither is convergent. $f(0) < g(0)$ but $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x>x_0$. Is it true that there always exists an $a$ where $a>x_0$ such that $f(a) = g(a)$?

This is for one of my Physics homework that involves proving that a transcendental equation has exactly one solution. Graphically I can show that a solution seems to always exist, but I am having trouble proving it algebraically. Since the equation is transcendental, there is no analytical solution so I thought maybe a general theorem like the one I stated could be helpful. Unfortunately, because I'm bad at Maths, I don't know if that statement is actually true.

The equation is:
$$e^{-ka/2} +  e^{ka/2} = \frac{\hbar^2k}{m\alpha}e^{ka/2}$$
And I need to prove that there is always exactly one solution for $k$ for every $a$, $m$, and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true in general. Consider

$$f(x)=  1-e^{-x}$$ and $$g(x) = 2.$$

Then $f(0) < g(0)$ and $$f'(x) = e^{-x} > 0 = g'(x),$$

but you can see there is no intersection.

However, if you have instead that for some $a,b$ with $a<b$

$$f(a) < g(a)$$ and

$$f(b) > g(b)$$

you will have a $c$, such that $a<c<b$ where

$$f(c)=g(c)$$ as long as $f$ and $g$ are continuous. This follows from applying the intermediate value theorem to $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: 'Neither f nor g is convergent'. In your example, f converges to 1.

Comment: Take my example and add $x$ to both functions.